# Wrap response in Tomcat custom valve to allow reading the response body

Tags: tomcat, logging, request, response, tomcat-valve

i need to log all response from an application using tomcat ValveBase class. For request i already created a wrapper org.apache.catalina.connector.Request and it logs all request. But for response, wrapper for org.apache.catalina.connector.Response is giving payload as null.can anybody help?

Comment: Is it a *requirement* that you use `ValveBase`? Or is that just how you have decided to solve the original problem?

Comment: Yes i don't want to change legacy existing application. Using filter i have to change in web.xml. Using Valvebase, when i implemented RequestWrapper i dont have to change existing application web.xml.But for Response i am not able to implement it wrapper.

Comment: https://github.com/codekoenig/RequestLoggerValve/tree/b580cc91a9a21e6e7c8596e9dc988b0aa504c04f/capture/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/connector. followed this link for RequestWrapper

Comment: If you are able to wrap the request, wrapping the response should not be too much of a problem. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use `ValveBase`, here is a `Filter` which may do what you are looking for. Note that using this will use-up a lot of memory for each request and reduce your performance, especially for very large responses.

The code is a little too long to put into an SO answer, so I'll just link to it.

https://markmail.org/message/kholzdskue5pctpw